# Neo4j -- WHERE, ORDER BY, and LIMIT after UNION

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to do a query that involves a UNION, but filters with a WHERE, ORDER BY, and LIMIT after the union.

The basic idea is to find all posts STARRED or POSTED by users that another user FOLLOWS. For example, the posts `s` and `p` are the posts of interest.

```
MATCH (a:USER {id:0})-[:FOLLOWS]->(b:USER),
      (b)-[:STARRED]->(s:POST),
      (b)-[:POSTED]->(p:POST)
```

I'd like to return the union of the id property of both `s` and `p` after filtering, sorting, and limiting the results. Any relevant indexes to create that make this query efficient would be helpful as well.

If `u` is the union of `s` and `p`, I'd want to do something like:

```
WHERE u.time > 1431546036148
RETURN u.id ORDER BY u.time SKIP 0 LIMIT 20
```

I don't know how to get `u` from `s` and `p`, and I don't know what indexes to create to make this query efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple relationships types so you'll not have to do UNION.

I guess the time property is on the `POST` node :

```
MATCH (user:USER {id:0})-[:FOLLOWS]->(friend:USER)
MATCH (friend)-[:STARRED|:POSTED]->(p:POST)
WHERE p.time > 1431546036148
RETURN p
ORDER BY p.time
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: well that was a simple solution :)